# How can I get better output from Artisan commands?

Tags: laravel

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Parse
>   error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED)

That's all I get. Any chance of a class name? The line causing the error? Anything at all that would help me narrow this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check last record in `/storage/logs/laravel.log` file.

Also, you could use route for the command to display full exception message:

```
Route::get('test-my-command', function() {
    Artisan::call('my:command');
});
```